# Why does the method of an HTTP Request accept any word?

Tags: http, http-post, httprequest

I've been playing around with `AJAX` sending data to an API REST done with PHP. At any point I have decided to specify `ASD` as the request method. Then I allowed the function linked to the API route to accept `ASD` as method and in PHP I've done this:

```
$incomingData = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

To my surprise, `$incomingData` wasn't null and the server didn't throw any exception or error but `$incomingData` had the spected value.

I am surprised because I've been some days reading about the uses of each one of the request methods (`POST`, `PUT`, `GET`, `PATCH`, etc) and in which cases it's more appropiate to use one or another. I've found a lot of good practices and recommendations, so I supposed that the type of the method was something good delimited to the last values mentioned.

So why is that? why does it accept any word? and then, what's the point to use each one of them for specific cases?

Answer (score 0):

The best source is [RFC 7231  - http metod overview](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4), that obsoletes [RFC 2616 on HTTP Method](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html#sec5.1.1)

[HTTP methods can be expanded](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html#sec5.1.1). There is also a [Method Registry](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-8.1)

There are [many already registered](http://www.iana.org/assignments/http-methods/http-methods.xhtml#methods) methods that are not very commonly used. Only GET and HEAD must be supported by a general purpose server.

Servers may limit the methods supported by a certain URI but normally **you need to write code or configuration for this purpose**. When the methods are limited a server SHOULD answer with a [405](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.6) if the method is known but not supported, including in the response a list of supported methods in the `Allow` response header, or 501 if method is unknown.